# QTableWidget ordering of column labels

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I have this table that I am trying to create. **I want the columns to be sorted exactly as I input it**. However, when the table displays, the table columns shows the column labels in some random order, e.g., A, C, B, E, D, G, F, H.

```
class MyTable(Observer):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.myTable = QTableWidget(0, len(data))
        self.myTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(data)

data = QStringList()

dataSet = {'A' , 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'}

for key in dataSet:
    data << key

table = MyTable(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
data = QStringList(['A' , 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'G'])

table = MyTable(data)
```